# Dynamically creating vertically grouped radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically creating several vertically grouped radio buttons using jQuery mobile 1.0 for a multiple choice quiz.

When I paste this code from the [JQM Radio Button Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/) in it styles the controlgroup properly.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>
</fieldset>
```

When I dynamically inject my markup on `pageshow()` it injects the proper markup but it doesn't style the control group at all.

```
$.getJSON("assets/json/aircraft.json", function (data) {
    var maxQuestions = 10;
    var maxChoices = 4;

    var randomsorted = data.aircraft.sort(function (a, b) {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });

    var quiz = $.grep(randomsorted, function (item, i) {
        return i < (maxQuestions * maxChoices);
    });

    var arr_quiz_markup = [];
    $.each(quiz, function (i, item) {
        var q = Math.floor(i / maxChoices);
        var c = i % maxChoices;

        if (c == 0) arr_quiz_markup.push("<div>Image for question " + q + " goes here...</div><fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-question='" + q + "'>");

        arr_quiz_markup.push("<input type='radio' name='q" + q + "' id='q" + q + "c" + c + "' data-aircraftid='" + item.id + "' />");
        arr_quiz_markup.push("<label for='q" + q + "c" + c + "'>" + item.name + "</label>");

        if (c == maxChoices - 1 || c == quiz.length - 1) arr_quiz_markup.push("</fieldset><br />");

    });

    $("#questions").html(arr_quiz_markup.join("")).controlgroup("refresh");
});
```

I tried `$("#questions :radio").checkboxradio("refresh");` but throws `"cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"`.

[My Live Quiz Demo](http://greghartshorne.com/vacr/#quiz) (Sorry, `jsfiddle` doesn't have jQuery Mobile listed)

What am I doing wrong? How do I refresh this to properly get JQM to style the controlgroup correctly?

Comment: jsFiddle lets you "Manage resources" to add jQuery Mobile. See http://jsfiddle.net/elijahmanor/5xwE8/ left nav try adding this url http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.js in YOUR jsFiddle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this line

```
$("#quiz").trigger("create");
```

after

```
$("#questions").html(arr_quiz_markup.join("")).controlgroup("refresh");
```

This code snippet will force a rebuild of the quiz page so that jqm styles will be applied to the page contents.

Answer (score 3):

You will get more information about the dynamic in this [jQuery Forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/applying-styles-to-dynamically-added-radio-buttons).

The jQuery Mobile default styles will be applied once you use the following code. That's what I found and it's working for me.

```
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.0):

#### HTML

```
<div id="locations" data-role="controlgroup"></div>
```

#### JS

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Hide loading message
        $.mobile.loading("hide");

        // Build page
        $("#location-page").trigger("create");

        // Clear another previos radio options
        $("#locations").controlgroup("container")["empty"]();

        // Read XML response
        var rows = $("Row", data);

        $(rows).each(function(index, value) {
            var locationId = $("LocationID", this).text();
            var locationName = $("LocationName", this).text();
            var $el = $("<label for=\"location" + index + "\">" + locationName + "</label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"location\" id=\"location" + index + "\" value=\"" + locationId + "\">")
            $("#locations").controlgroup("container")["append"]($el);
            $($el[1]).checkboxradio();
        });
        $("#locations").controlgroup("refresh");

        // Change to locations' page
        $.mobile.changePage("#location-page", {transition: "flip"});
    },
    ...
});
```